# PyQt5 - Double press same keyboard key

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, keyevent, qkeyevent

I am handling multiple key presses by subclassing `QMainWindow` and overriding the `keyPressEvent` and `keyReleaseEvent` functions, and then updating a dictionary if the key is down or not...

```py
  def keyPressEvent(self,event):
    self.pressedKeys[event.key()] = True

  def keyReleaseEvent(self,event):
    self.pressedKeys[event.key()] = False
```

... and the `pressedKeysArray` being:

```py
  pressedKeys = {Qt.Key_Left: False,
                 Qt.Key_Right: False,
                 Qt.Key_Down: False,
                 Qt.Key_Up: False}
```

However, I would like to be able to catch a double right arrow click, say within 100 or 200 milliseconds of each other. I would expand the `pressedKeys` dictionary to include double clicked keys that can be set to `True` or `False`, but I don't know how to know if the key has been pressed twice in quick succession.

Here is my code so far:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  pressedKeys = {Qt.Key_Left: False,
                 Qt.Key_Right: False,
                 Qt.Key_Down: False,
                 Qt.Key_Up: False}

  def __init__(self,parent=None,*args,**kwargs):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs)
    self.parent = parent

    self.timer = QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.keyAction)
    self.timer.start(50)

    self.show()

  def keyPressEvent(self,event):
    self.pressedKeys[event.key()] = True

  def keyReleaseEvent(self,event):
    self.pressedKeys[event.key()] = False

  def keyAction(self):
    if self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Left] and self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Down]: print("rolling left")

    elif self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Right] and self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Down]: print("rolling right")

    elif self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Left]: print("running left")

    elif self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Right]: print("running right")

    elif self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Down]: print("crouching") #return here to block effect of 'up' key being pressed

    if self.pressedKeys[Qt.Key_Up]: print("jumping")

def exceptHook(exectype,value,traceback):
  sys.__excepthook__(exectype,value,traceback)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  sys.excepthook = exceptHook
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  mainWindow = MainWindow()
  app.quit()
```

Comment: Explain in more detail what you want and then point out what your attempt is to solve it.

Comment: I would like to be able to know when a key is pressed twice in quick succession, and set a variable to true when this happens. I'm not sure where to start with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to keep a property `last_pressed` to keep track of the most recent pressed key. Instead of using the timer to call `keyAction`, just call `keyAction` from the key press and release events. Now in the `keyPressEvent` if the timer `isActive` and `last_pressed == event.key()`, you know it was a "double" key press. Otherwise, assign the last pressed key and start the timer. If the timer reaches timeout, reset `last_pressed`.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    pressedKeys = {Qt.Key_Left: False, Qt.Key_Right: False,
                   Qt.Key_Down: False, Qt.Key_Up: False}

    def __init__(self,parent=None,*args,**kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.last_pressed = None

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.clear_pressed)

        self.show()

    def clear_pressed(self):
        self.last_pressed = None

    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        self.pressedKeys[event.key()] = True
        if self.timer.isActive():
            if self.last_pressed == event.key():
                print('Double')
                self.timer.stop()
        else:
            self.timer.start(200)
        self.last_pressed = event.key()
        self.keyAction()

    def keyReleaseEvent(self,event):
        self.pressedKeys[event.key()] = False
        self.keyAction()
```